# cannot change datatype from "from_dict" of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

After `df['a'].astype(float)` from `from_dict` cannot be sum the column.
I expected the `sum(a)` should be 15 not 159 and I just want to show `15` only not whole dataframe table

**code**

```
x = [{'a': '1','b1': '2','b2': '3', 'c': '4'},{'a': '5','b1': '6','b2': '7','c': '8'},{'a': '9','b1': '10','b2': '11','c': '12'}]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x)

df['a'] = df['a'].astype(float)
df['total'] = df['a'].sum()
df
```

**code output:**

```
    a   b1  b2  c   total
0   1.0 2   3   4   15.0
1   5.0 6   7   8   15.0
2   9.0 10  11  12  15.0
```

**Data type**

```
df['a'].astype(float)
df.dtypes

a        float64
b1       object
b2       object
c        object
total    object
dtype: object
```

**Expected Result**

```
15
```

Comment: When type casting, reassign the result to the column `df['a'] = df['a'].astype(float)`. Then to get the result of 15 only simply store in a variable, not a column : `total = df['a'].sum()`. The reason you are getting 159 is due to string concatenation because you are not casting to a float properly.

Comment: since it is sum of column, it showed in each row is quit strange, so i want to thinking of any simplify method to just show **15** after run the code

Comment: In Pandas, if you assign a new column to a float, it will populate the whole column with that number. In your code, to show 15 after running add `total = df['a'].sum()` and then `print(total)` since total will now only contain 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After converting `a` to `float` you should save it like this:

```
df['a']=df['a'].astype(float)
```

Comment: dear, any simplify method to just show my answe only **15**

Comment: Do you mean to print it as an integer and not as float? if so, try this `df['total'] = df['a'].sum().astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Use
df['a']=pd.to_numeric(df['a'],errors='coerce')
To change the type

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).